# Join three table associations in postgres with sequelize and where the third association has null values - Nested include

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have three tables that are associated with one another in a nested order, say A hasMany B and B hasOne C.

to say precisely, consider my table name as an assignment, question and answer.

While the assignment would have so many questions and question would have an answer answered by each student.

Now I need a filter to get the questions which is unanswered by a student.

My query looks like,

```
const assignments = await Assignments.findAndCountAll({
  where: [
    condition,
    sequelize.where(sequelize.col('questions.answer.id'), 'IS', null),
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: AssignmentQuestion,
      as: 'questions',
      duplicating: false,
      include: {
        model: AssignmentQuestionAnswer,
        as: 'answer',
        where: {
          stdentId: req.user.id,
        },
        required: false,
      },
    },
  ],
  distinct: true,
  offset: 1,
  limit: 10,
  order: [['createdAt, 'asc']],
});
```

the issue I'm having with this code is even if the limit is 10 and total count is 12 I'll get only 6 rows at page 1. Below are my associations;

```
Assignments.hasMany(models.AssignmentQuestion, {
    foreignKey: 'assignmentId',
    as: 'questions',
});

AssignmentQuestion.hasOne(models.AssignmentQuestionAnswer, {
    foreignKey: 'questionId',
    as: 'answer',
});
```

is there a way to fix the issue???

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `where:{id: null, stdentId: req.user.id,}` in your nested include instead of `sequelize.where()`?

You can share the loggin sql? Idk if the `sequelize.where` is overrading one `required:false` or something like this (i suspect not, but you can try?)